# Parsing fetched JSON to dictionary in Swift 3

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

At some point in my app the user supplies a movie name. The controller will get more info about the movie from [OMDB](http://omdbapi.com) and store it. I run into problems getting converting the JSON from the url into a dictionary. Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func addMovieButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // get title from the text field and prepare it for insertion into the url
    let movieTitle = movieTitleField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    // get data for the movie the user named
    let movieData = getMovieData(movieTitle: movieTitle)
    // debug print statement
    print(movieData)
    // reset text field for possible new entry
    movieTitleField.text = ""
}

// function that retrieves the info about the movie and converts it to a dictionary
private func getMovieData(movieTitle: String) -> [String: Any] {

    // declare a dictionary for the parsed JSON to go in
    var movieData = [String: Any]()

    // prepare the url in proper type
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=\(movieTitle)")

    // get the JSON from OMDB, parse it and store it into movieData
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        do {
            movieData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }).resume()

    // return the data
    return movieData
}
```

I have tried many variations of the URLSession part that I found on Stackoverflow and I know that the data is successfully fetched:
[image: screenshot]

However I don't know how to properly get at it and turn it into a dictionary I can then use in the rest of my app. The print statement in the IBAction function always returns an empty dictionary.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40810108/2976878 – http://stackoverflow.com/q/40014830/2976878 – http://stackoverflow.com/q/27081062/2976878 – http://stackoverflow.com/q/31264172/2976878 – http://stackoverflow.com/q/25203556/2976878

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into completion blocks and asynchronous functions. Your `getMovieData` is returning before the datatask's completion handler is called.

Your function, instead of returning, will call the completion block passed in and should change to:

```
private func getMovieData(movieTitle: String, completion: @escaping ([String:Any]) -> Void) {

    // declare a dictionary for the parsed JSON to go in
    var movieData = [String: Any]()

    // prepare the url in proper type
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=\(movieTitle)")

    // get the JSON from OMDB, parse it and store it into movieData
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        do {
            movieData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            completion(movieData)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Ah! I understand now. This is a direction I didn't think of myself. I will look into how asynchronous functions work, work out how to write out the function that is called on completion and how to call this async function. Thank you!